# EntityFramework: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, azure-functions

below is the code :
AddJobCommand.cs

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<JobViewModel> Handle(EditJobCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (command.JobViewModel == null) throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Empty request.");
            var jobViewModel = command.JobViewModel;

            try
            {
                var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel);
                job.Id = command.Id;

                OnBeforeAttach(job);

                _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>().Attach(job);
                _context.MarkModified(job);
                
                OnBeforeSave(job);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return jobViewModel;
            }
catch (DbUpdateException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }

protected void OnBeforeAttach(Job job)
        {
            if (job.Notes != null)
            {
                var newNote = job.Notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.IsNew);
                if (newNote != null)
                {
                    newNote.JobId = job.Id;
                    //UpdateAccessInfo(newNote);
                    _context.Set<JobNote>().Attach(newNote);
                    _context.Entry(newNote).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnBeforeSave(Job job)
            {
            var entry = _context.Entry(job);
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            entry.Property(j => j.Name).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.Description).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.SAPCode).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.InitiatedOn).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.EndDate).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.ProjectId).IsModified = true;
            
        }
        }
public void MarkModified(IEntity entity)
        {
            var entry = Entry(entity);
            if (entity.IsNew)
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entry.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                entry.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
            }
        }
```

EditJob.cs

```
[FunctionName("EditJob")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "put", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)            
        {
            if (!_authorizationService.IsAuthorized(req))
            {
                return _httpResponseHelper.ToUnAuthorizedResult();
            }
            string idValue = req.Query["id"];
            if (idValue == null)
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a id on the query string");
            int id = int.Parse(idValue);
            string requestBody = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            JobViewModel jobViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobViewModel>(requestBody);
            var job = await _mediator.Send(new EditJobCommand(id, jobViewModel));
            return new OkObjectResult(job);

            
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the exception on await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); line in EditJobCommand.cs file
Nobody is trying to update the record at same time. Not sure what is the root cause of the exception. I have tried adding OptimisticConcurrencyException in the catch block , but i dont want to add the code to save changes there in catch block.